# LiveWire & Laravel Component: Html Not SHOW UP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-10, laravel-components

I'm working with Laravel v10 and in my project I tried the following to make a custom component with livewire.

I ran: `php artisan make:component CounterDisplay`

created a new file named: `resources/views/components/counter-display.blade.php` which goes like this:

```
<div>
    Counter Value: {{ $count }}
</div>
```

Then ran `php artisan make:livewire Counter` to created a new livewire component (`app/Http/Livewire/Counter.php`):

```
// app/Livewire/Counter.php
namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Counter extends Component
{
    public $count = 0;

    public function increment()
    {
        $this->count++;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.counter');
    }
}
```

Then created a new blade file `resources/views/livewire/counter.blade.php`:

```
<!-- resources/views/livewire/counter.blade.php -->
<div>
    <button wire:click="increment">Increment</button>
    <x-counter-display :count="$count" />
</div>
```

With this route:

```
use App\Livewire\Counter;

Route::get('/counter', function () {
    return view('counter', ['counter' => Counter::class]);
});
```

And also created a blade file named `counter.blade.php`:

```
<!-- resources/views/counter.blade.php -->
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <livewire:counter />
@endsection
```

Now when I visit the **`/counter`**, nothing show up!

However when I check `dd` at `counter-display.blade.php`,:

```
@dd(2) <!-- Properly returns 2 but the html not show up -->
<div>
    Counter Value: {{ $count }}
</div>
```

It will show the output but strange that the even the **Counter Value:** text is not printed while there is no error.

So if you have any idea what's going wrong about this, please let me know...

I'm really stuck with this!

Comment: What's the html looks like when you inspect the source on the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You would call the livewire component on your blade like

```
@livewire('counter')
```

Comment: I did call the livewire component at blade (`counter.blade.php`): `<livewire:counter />`

Answer (score 0):

You have generated *CounterDisplay* using:

> php artisan make:component CounterDisplay

so I suppose you have both *counter-display.blade.php* and */View/Components/CounterDisplay.php*

To let $counter reach *counter-display.blade.php* you must manage it in the constructor of *CounterDisplay.php*:

```php
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\View\Component;

class CounterDisplay extends Component
{
    public function __construct(public int $count)
    {
    }

    public function render(): View|Closure|string
    {
        return view('components.counter-display');
    }
}
```

or if you prefer the 'classic' way:

```
// .....

class CounterDisplay extends Component
{
    public int $count;


    public function __construct(int $count)
    {
        $this->count = $count;
    }

    // .....
}
```

Otherwise you can delete */View/Components/CounterDisplay.php* and declare the $count property directly in the *counter-display.blade.php* view:

```html
@props (['count'])

<div>
    Counter Value: {{ $count }}
</div>
```

after you have done these modifications, it is advisable to run:

> composer dump-autoload
> php artisan view:clear

Comment: I've added some post-modification instructions